# Issues of migrating Worklight from v6.0 to v6.1

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, worklight-studio

Migrating my project(made up of 3 apps and 2 adapters) from Worklight v6.0 to Worklight v6.1 i'm facing problems over adapters migration.

I had already deployed .war, .wlapp and .adapter files in production environment using an Ant script(for .war file). 
The application server used is Websphere, the dbms server used is Derby.

I upgraded the worklight studio's plugin to the latest version, created a new, clean workspace, exported the project from the old workspace and imported in the new one.

For what concerns development environment everything works.

For what concerns production environment i successfully deployed all the applications(but don't work yet becouse the adapters lack). 
When i try to deploy the adapter(each one) i get the following exception:

```
Failed to deploy adapter 'adapter1.adapter'. The 'adapter' version '6.0.0' is different than the version of the Worklight project '6.1.0.00.20131219-1900'. Use Worklight Studio '6.1.0.00.20131219-1900' to build and deploy the application.
```

I tried also to create a new adapter and deploy it but i'm still getting the same error.

Comment: When you've imported the project into the 6.1.0 studio, there were no errors in the Eclipse console view? What about the Errors view?

Comment: What about when creating a new project and in it a new adapter, does this work?

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a test case application and send it over?

Comment: check weather your update has been finished and check weather your worklight Studio  plugin updated to 6.1

Comment: the project was imported into the 6.1.0 studio with no errors

Comment: i tried to create a new project with a simple adapter but still doesn't work. the exception launched is the same.

Comment: i created a simple project and a simple adapter, how can i send it to you @IdanAdar?

Comment: @KawineshSK the update has been finished successfully, i can deploy only applications but not adapters.

Comment: @Riccardo, Upload to Dropbox and provide download link.

Comment: i've got the same issue, and many errors in my server's log: [1/8/14 9:27:41:898 CET] 00000029 com.worklight.gadgets.serving.InvokeProcServlet              E FWLSE0074E: Failed synchronizing adapters from database. [project IDVS]

Comment: Thanks, but what would help is reproduction steps of what you do in 6.0 and then in 6.1

Comment: @IdanAdar https://www.dropbox.com/s/ykjxyiw0o2to2pe/exporthttpAdapter.zip it's a simple test adapter.

Comment: And the reproduction steps? import to Eclipse with WL 6.0.0.0, build and deploy app and adapter, export, import to Eclipse with 6.1.0.0, build and deploy?

Comment: The steps i did are the following: import to Eclipse with WL 6.1.0.0, Deploy Worklight Adapter, from the Worklight server console choose the .adapter file from the bin directory and upload. I uploaded in dropbox the compiled file too(https://www.dropbox.com/s/lpprf1bevef2u3p/httpAdapter.adapter)

Comment: what do you mean exactly for building the adapter? is there a specific procedure?

Comment: Don't be cheap please :) export your entire test project from Eclipse, the Worklight project... not just a zip containing the adapter files.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/hdobmkrodh2bphy/exportContoContabile.zip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Edited the answer entirely based on edits to the question*

All artifacts produced by Worklight Studio: `.adapter`, `.wlapp` and `.war` must be generated using the same Worklight Studio version.

Make sure that after importing the project to Worklight 6.1, that you are building *all* the the project's applications and adapters.

Next, you need to deploy the re-generated `.war` file and then deploy the `.wlapp` and `.adapter` files.

To verify that the adapter is of the same version as the project's `.war` file, extract the `.adapter` file from the `bin` folder and open the `XML` file. You should see the platform version like this:

```
<ns2:adapter xmlns:ns2="http://www.worklight.com/integration"
name="test" platformVersion="6.1.0.00.20131126-0630">
```

IBM Worklight Information Center topics to read:

- [Installing and configuring](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/topics/c_install_config.html)
- [Upgrading from one version of IBM Worklight to another](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.upgrade.doc/topics/t_upgrading.html)

You can also see this in Worklight Console > About > Additional Support Information:

[image]

Comment: do you have any specific configuration applied to the adapter deployment? it looks like that the weird behaviour i get is due to the Eclipse configuration.

Comment: None. It's just Eclipse Java EE 4.2.2 ("Juno" SR2) with Worklight Studio Developer Edition and Google ADT plug-in.

Comment: to deploy the .war project file did you use Ant after customizing the configure-liberty-derby.xml configuration file?

Comment: What? What ever for? We are talking here about 2 Eclipse instances, each with a Worklight Studio plug-in... you just import your exported Worklight project and that's it. What are you not telling me? What else is there in your project? Is this whole question in fact not about Development environment but Production (in other words, not about Eclipse at all...)?

Comment: yes, i'm talking about production environment, apps and adapters works on development environment for me also. I have the problems i described on the production environment. the only thing i added is the production server settings(right click on any app -> Build Setting and deployment target)

Comment: Edit your question to properly convey what you are doing. That is, mention that after importing and building your project in 6.1, you then proceed to deploy these artifacts (your .adapter, .wlapp and .war files) to your Production environment. How can you not mention such an important detail? There is no Studio in a production environment, there is an application serer (WAS, Tomcat), that you deploy your artifacts to the installed Worklight Server on that application server.

Comment: The only thing comes to mind is that you did not deploy your WAR file to the production server, meaning it is still using the old one and this is why it does not recognize the adapter.

Comment: ok i just edited my question. tried to deploy it again several times but still doesn't work.

Comment: Edited my answer as well.

Comment: is there any way to figure out the version number directly on the .war, .adapter and .wlapp files?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44797/discussion-between-riccardo-and-idan-adar)

Comment: You must make sure that you have deployed the updated .war file to the production server; you get this error because something in your production server did not update.